# Timing Diagram in Emacs Org Mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, plantuml

What is a good way to draw this kind of timing diagram in Emacs Org Mode?

```
Terminal A -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            |   ^                ^               ^   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            \/  |                |               |   \/  \/

Terminal B -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

( I don't want to draw it vertically like as a usual sequence chart ).

Could you let me know a way or even better if you have?

PS : I googled to find an example written in *ditaa*, *plantuml* and etc, but couldn't find any..

Answer (score 6):

Easiest I can think of is to use ditaa, 
and the actual manual page is an example written in ditaa, with a button to look at the org-file source code: 
[manual](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-ditaa.html). Don't know how you missed that page googling org-mode and ditaa...

Anyways here your graph in org-mode, it is almost literally the same:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file flowchart.png
Terminal A --------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |   ^                ^               ^   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            |   |                |               |   |   |
            v                    |               |   v   v
Terminal B --------------------------------------------------------------------------

#+END_SRC
#+header: :exports results

#+RESULTS:
[[file:flowchart.png]]
```

Which will export to:
[image]

Just make sure you actually have ditaa.jar on your system and org can see it.
Also evaluate your code with `C-c C-c`  or automatize it enabling code execution on export ([security implications!](http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html#Code-evaluation-security)).